# Creating a table inside a node in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I'm trying to create a table inside a node in tikz ( the main purpose is to have two arrows next to my table. But the table format changes. Specifically, the columns are out of the picture.

```
 \tcbset{tab2/.style={enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,
colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title}}




\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node 
        {



\begin{table}[htb]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\refstepcounter{table}
\begin{tcolorbox}[tab2,tabularx={p{3cm}|Y|Y}]
\footnotesize{-} & \footnotesize{a}& \footnotesize{b}\\\hline\hline
\footnotesize{c} & \footnotesize{d}&\footnotesize{f} \\\hline\hline
\footnotesize{g} & \footnotesize{h}& \footnotesize{i}\\\hline\hline
\footnotesize{j } & \footnotesize{l} & \footnotesize{m}\\\hline\hline
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{table}
};
\draw[very thick, ->] (-6,-2) -- (-6,2) node[midway,above,sloped] {dimension 1};
 \draw[very thick, ->] (-5,-2) -- (4,-2) node[midway,above,sloped] {dimension2};   
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: picture]

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment. Are you setting the text width for the node?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `text width` of the node to something that will make your table fit in the frame.

Some other comments:

- You don't need to wrap your table in a `table` environment.
- `\footnotesize` is a switch and does not take an argument. You should use it as `\footnotesize ...` instead of `\footnotesize{...}`
- if you are already creating your table as a node, you could use the node's coordinates for your arrows

```
\documentclass[xcolor={svgnames,table}]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\tcbset{
  tab2/.style={
    enhanced,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    colframe=red!50!black,
    colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
    coltitle=black,
    center title
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[text width=.8\linewidth,font=\footnotesize] (table) {
    \begin{tcolorbox}[tab2,tabularx={|X|X|X|}]
      - & a & b\\\hline\hline
      c & d & f\\\hline\hline
      g & h & i\\\hline\hline
      j & l & m\\\hline\hline
    \end{tcolorbox}
  };
  \draw[very thick, ->] ([xshift=-0.4cm]table.south west) -- ([xshift=-0.4cm]table.north west) node[midway,above,sloped] {dimension 1};
  \draw[very thick, ->] ([yshift=-0.4cm]table.south west) -- ([yshift=-0.4cm]table.south east) node[midway,below,sloped] {dimension2};   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Internet is amazing! Thank you!

Comment: @ka208qq Answering would have been much easier if you had included a class and the necessary packages in your question so that we don't have to guess them. Please keep this in mind for future questions.